# API bridge for Symbian

Tags: java-me, symbian

i want to read Sms from a Symbian Mobile and send the Sms to a server. am not conversant with symbian programming languages so i want to use J2ME and interface with API_BRIDGE. my problem is i cant find any examples on how to use API_BRIDGE with J2ME. kindly assist with articles or examples of using api_bridge.

Comment: there are good reasons why using api_bridge is not such a good idea and good reasons why there aren't more articles and examples. it may be possible to do what you want in pure j2me. are you really sure you want to use api_bridge?

Comment: @QuickRecipesOnSymbianOS am not familiar with symbian programming hence the reason i chose Api_Bridge. am more into j2me so i wanted to limit coding in symbian. i would highly appreciate if you assist me on how i would do it in pure j2me. consider that messages are to be read from inbox of the device and the message is not prefixed with a port number.

Comment: symbian programmers help to solve this mystery. how can i integrate j2me with API_Bridge on symbian mobile Phones.

Answer (score 0):

All relevant information about API Bridge for J2ME is here:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/J2ME_Api_Bridge_Interface

As you can see, it currently doesn't support reading the SMS database. It's possible if you're willing to (1) Write the sms plugin in Symbian C++, package and sign it yourself or (2) Hunt for a plugin already created by someone else

I've tried option 2 for you but failed. Hopefully you'll have better luck / searching skills.

Another thing you need to be aware of is API Bridge can only be installed on Symbian S60, Anna and Belle/Belle Refresh. If you're using Symbian S40 / Asha then sorry, you're out of luck. As far as I know, there are no known methods of accessing the SMS database from J2ME on those devices.